# Draw a truncated octahedron packing in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, image3d, polyhedra, packing

Consider a truncated octahedron composed by

- 24 vertices (4×6)
- 14 faces (contain 6 squares and 8 hexagons)
- 36 edges (4×6+6×82=36).

This truncated octahedron can pack and tessellate the 3-dimensional-space like this.

> Question: What are the available methods to draw this in Mathematica? (My attempt was that I showed such packing is possible and prepared this figure [not using Mathematica..].)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g = PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron", "Faces", "Polygon"];

u = {2, 0, Sqrt[2]};
v = {0, 2, -Sqrt[2]};
w = {0, 2, Sqrt[2]};
Graphics3D[
 Table[
  {Opacity[0.7], RandomChoice[{Orange, Blue}],
   GeometricTransformation[g, 
    TranslationTransform[i u + j v + k w]]},
  {i, 3}, {j, 3}, {k, 3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks +1, but I am not sure the object you draw can do packing/tessellation in 3D...?

Comment: maybe of interests too https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214858